# Is there a way to keep main thread in sleep mode until all my threads finish their execution in java?

Tags: java, multithreading

I have Two thread class named Player1 and player2.First player1 Will start scoring run.Now player2 is in waiting state and once player1 completed his game then player2 will get chance for playing.

Once both players are completing, then i have to summarize the score of both players.

Most of all, i completed all the work.But i couldn't make Main Thread(to print summary of the players) wait until all players are completed.

This is my Java Program...

```
class Player1 extends Thread
{  
    private Object o;  
    int total=0;  
    Player1 (Object o)
    {  
      this.o = o;  
    }  

    public void run()
    {  
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+ 
                           " is running now...");  
        for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
        {  
             ++total ;  
        }  
        System.out.println(this.getName()+" is "+total+ 
                           " Run! and finished ");  
        synchronized (o)
        {  
            o.notify();  
        } 
    }
}  

class Player2 extends Thread 
{  
    private Object o;  
    int total=0;
    Player2 (Object o)
    {  
      this.o = o;  
    }  
    public void run()
    {  
        try
        {  
            synchronized (o) 
            {  
                o.wait();  
            } 
        }  
        catch (Exception e) 
        {  
            e.printStackTrace();  
        }  
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+ 
                           " is running now");  

        for(int i=0;i<15;i++)
        {  
             ++total ;  
        }  
        System.out.println(this.getName()+" is "+total+ 
                           " Run! and finished ");  
    }  
}  

public class MultiThreading
{  
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {  
        Object lock= new Object();  

        Player1 Amir=new Player1(lock);  
        Amir.setName("Amir");

        Player2 Hossein=new Player2(lock);  
        Hossein.setName("Hossein");  

        Amir.start();  
        Hossein.start();  


        System.out.println("Amir Score is :"+Amir.total);
        System.out.println("Hossein Score is :"+Hossein.total);
    }  

}
```

The Output is :

```
Amir Score is :0
Hossein Score is :0
Amir is running now...
Amir is 10 Run! and finished 
Hossein is running now
Hossein is 15 Run! and finished
```

In my output,the summary of the game is printed by main thread before player started the game actually (Amir Score is :0, Hossein Score is :0).I could use Thread.Sleep(3000) then the answer is correct.But That is not good way, i think...

Could you please enlighten me on this...

Expecting your valuable reply...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use the [`Thread.join()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#join%28%29) method:

```
Amir.start();  
Hossein.start();

Amir.join();
Hossein.join();
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use a `CountdownLatch`.  Create a `CountdownLatch(2)` before creating the 2 `Thread` classes, and pass that `CountdownLatch` into the constructor for the two threads.  Then, in the main code, call `latch.await()`.  This will block and wait for the other threads to both call `latch.countDown()` and will only continue after that happens.  You just need to make each thread call `latch.countDown()` after finishing their work so control goes back to the code that will do the summary.

```
class Player1 extends Thread
{  
    private Object o;  
    int total=0;
    private latch:CountDownLatch;  
    Player1 (Object o, CountDownLatch latch)
    {  
      this.o = o;  
      this.latch = latch;
    }  

    public void run()
    {  
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+ " is running now...");  
        for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
        {  
             ++total ;  
        }  
        System.out.println(this.getName()+" is "+total+ " Run! and finished ");  
        synchronized (o)
        {  
            o.notify();  
        } 
        latch.countDown();
    }
}  

class Player2 extends Thread 
{  
    private Object o;  
    int total=0;
    private CountDownLatch latch;
    Player2 (Object o, CountDownLatch latch)
    {  
      this.o = o;  
      this.latch = latch;
    }  
    public void run()
    {  
        try
        {  
            synchronized (o) 
            {  
                o.wait();  
            } 
        }  
        catch (Exception e) 
        {  
            e.printStackTrace();  
        }  
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+ " is running now");  

        for(int i=0;i<15;i++)
        {  
             ++total ;  
        }  
        System.out.println(this.getName()+" is "+total+ " Run! and finished "); 
        latch.countDown(); 
    }  
}  

public class MultiThreading
{  
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {  
        Object lock= new Object();  
        CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(2);
        Player1 Amir=new Player1(lock, latch);  
        Amir.setName("Amir");

        Player2 Hossein=new Player2(lock, latch);  
        Hossein.setName("Hossein");  

        Amir.start();  
        Hossein.start();  

        latch.await();
        System.out.println("Amir Score is :"+Amir.total);
        System.out.println("Hossein Score is :"+Hossein.total);
    }  

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Thread.join allows one thread to wait for another to complete before it continues its execution. That may help you.